# Jira ITSM Cloud - Automatization- JQL Count total issues in a status for an agent and do

Tags: count, jira, status, agent, jql

Cloud you please help me with the correct JQL to build the following automation rule to work:

Whenever an issue is transitioned from status "Assigned" to status "In Progress", run a JQL or Advanced Compare or Lookup issues (or something else) in which to check:

==> IF the assigned user on the issue (current assignee), has the TOTAL number (count) of issues "In Progress" in the project greater than 0

=> THEN : do nothing (and let the user take the issue in progress )

=> ELSE : transition issue from status "In Progress" to status "Assigned"

-- How to make that JQL ?

Thank you very much in advance,

Alex

Comment: I have tried with Lookup issues to have: 'status = "In Progress"  AND assignee = issue.assignee.id'     but it just doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make an automation rule, to lookup issues, and with the following code:

status = "In Progress" AND assignee = {{issue.assignee}}

WARN: The validate query wont work, but the rule as a whole works.